# Quick normalizer for wav files not working as intended

Tags: c#, naudio

I wrote a quick wave file normalizer in c# using naudio.

Currently it locks the thread and creates 1 KB files. `sm` is the highest peak of the file

```
using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(aktuellerPfad))
{
    using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter("temp.wav", reader.WaveFormat))
    {
        byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[reader.Length];
        int read = reader.Read(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length);
        writer.WriteSample(read *32768/sm);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is not working as intended?

Comment: You are trying to write the output value int read (which is a scalar value that i guess stands for the number of samples read) instead of the bytes buffer. I think that the solution of @ErAcube is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do mathematical operation in audio buffer to normalise the signal. The normalising steps would be:

a. Read audio buffer as you are doing. (Although, I would prefer reading in chunks).

```
    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[reader.Length];
    reader.Read( bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length );
```

b. Calculate multiplier value. There are different ways to calculate the value. I don't know how you are calculating but it looks the value is 32768/sm. I would denote multiplier as "mul".

c. Now iterate through the buffer and multiply the value with the multiplier.

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < bytesBuffer.Length; i++ )
  {
      bytesBuffer[i] = bytesBuffer[i] * mul;
  }
```

d. Finally, write samples to file.

```
writer.WriteSamples( bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length );
```

Comment: I would also check that the value of  `sm` is not 0 before using it for dividing.